# Torus: $S^1\times S^1$ homeomorphic to the parametric description?

Tags: general-topology

I have to show that $$f:S^1\times S^1\rightarrow T^2_{R,r}, f(e^{ia},e^{ib})=(R+rcos(a))cos(b),(R+rcos(a))sin(b),rsin(a))$$ is a bijection. I already showed f is injective, but then I have to show it is surjective, I think it is not very hard but I just don't know how to do it.

I do know that $f$ is surjective if for all $(R+rcos(a))cos(b),(R+rcos(a))sin(b),rsin(a))$, there exists an $(e^{ia},e^{ib})$ such that $f(e^{ia},e^{ib})=(R+rcos(a))cos(b),(R+rcos(a))sin(b),rsin(a))$, but I can't find a way to explain this is true.

After this, I have to explain this map in a picture en convince myself it is a homeomorphism..

Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: I think you already proved it by writing down the formula for $f$...maybe the only issue is that $f$ is well-defined.

Comment: yes, the formula was given.. but how do I prove it is well-defined?

Comment: If you proved it was injective that should give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that the definition of $f$ relies on the representation of points of $S^1 \times S^1$ as pairs of (complex) numbers of the form $(e^{ia}, e^{ib})$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.  In fact, $S^1 \times S^1$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, with projection map $\pi:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow S^1 \times S^1$  defined by $\pi(a,b) = (e^{ia}, e^{ib})$.  To study your map $f$, it's helpful to study the composition $F = f \circ \pi$, that is, the map $F(a,b) = f(e^{ia}, e^{ib})$.

For example, since $T^2_{R,r}$ is defined parametrically, and the domain of $F$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $F$ is clearly surjective.  This implies, in turn, that $f$ is surjective as well.

You can also use $F$ to argue that $f$ is well-defined, injective, continuous, etc.

Hope this helps!